# Use of "sort of"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is this a valid use of the expression "sort of"? Does it make any sense in the context of the phrase below?

I'm not happy at all. So now that I **sort of** got myself familiarized with this town you ask me to move to New York just because the big boss decided that I would be the best person to manage the new branch of our office.

Comment: In this case, you need to Google the entire phrase. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sort-of) offers good definitions

Comment: And note that it is **informal**.

Answer (score 1):

It means - now that I have just started getting familiar with the town - But it’s a familiar term and does not fit the rest of your sentence